# Within Rails App, Bundler insists I am using Ruby 2.0 when I'm not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mountain-lion, gemfile

*Need some help figuring out why Rails app insists I'm using Ruby 2.0 when I'm not.*

***Using Mountain Lion/Macbook Pro*

In Gemfile I have:
`ruby '1.9.3'`

And have instructed RVM to use 1.9.3
`$ rvm --default use 1.9.3`

Which it is. Running a...
`$ rvm list`
Gives me a `=* ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]`

**But within the rails, whenever I try to:**
1. bundle
2. start the app
3. or even run `$ ruby -v`

I get a..
`Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3`

I'm using Mountain Lion. I do have Ruby 2.0.

`/usr/bin/ruby -v`
Shows `ruby 2.0.0p247`
Which is aliased to System Ruby
But this Ruby I am not using.

So, In this app I get:
`$ ruby -v`
`Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3`

Outside the app I get:
`$ ruby -v`
`ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]`

Comment: In your app, what happens when you run `rvm current`?  What happens when you type `rvm use ruby-1.9.3` then run `ruby -v` inside your app?  Inside your app directory do you have a file called `.ruby-version`?

Comment: Within Rails app, `rvm current` return `ruby-1.9.3-p484`. Running `rvm use ruby-1.9.3` return `Using /Users/georgenorris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484`. Then afterwards, `ruby -v` again returns `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3`

Comment: No .ruby-version file, only a `ruby '1.9.3'` in the Gemfile.

Comment: In my humble opinion the best and most efficient way to have ruby on your system is to use rvm for everything, even the installation. So you have a fully virtual environment for your app. /usr/bin/ruby is usually installed by your package manager (apt, yum, etc), not by rvm, so to change your SYSTEM configuration you should change the link of /usr/bin/ruby so it points to your 1.9.3 ruby binary ((Or in case you are not root, change your $PATH so your 1.9.3 folder is before /usr/bin ))

Comment: `cat .bundle/config` ?

Comment: No .bundle/config file in project, and no ~/.bundle either.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis The 2.0.0 install I guess came with Mountain Lion? I didn't install it. I use RVM for everything. In my ~/.zshrc if have: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` and then afterwards     
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS`. Does that order make any impact? I would assume RVM coming first is what is preferred?

Comment: @Gnee In my `~/.bashrc` I have `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` and in my `~/.bash_profile` I have `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`.  These were both added automatically during installation.  Make sure you have something similar.

Comment: @franksort Yes, I am wondering if I am missing that. When I installed RVM a `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` was added to my `~/.zshrc` but not the `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`. I used to have that, but when I reinstalled RVM today I didn't get it. Was thinking newer versions don't use that?  Looking into it..

Comment: And running `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` seems to delete that line.

Comment: Actually `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]]` was added to `.bash_profile` not to `.zshrc` which was where I was looking..

Comment: Got it working. Reinstalled RVM and Ruby. Whatever that did, it fixed it.